# How can get deptno number from user and print the all employees, belongs deptno 10 in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle

How can get deptno number from user and print the all employees, belongs deptno 10 in Oracle 11g

```
**Answer is
    declare
        cursor a(T number) is
        Select *from EMp where Deptno = T;
        Em a%rowtype;
    begin
        open a(&b);
            loop
            Fetch a into Em;
            exit when a%notfound;
            dbms_output.put_line(Em.EName);
            end loop;
    END;
    /**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare

    cursor a(T number) is
    Select *from EMp where Deptno = T;
    Em a%rowtype;
begin
    open a(&b);
        loop
        Fetch a into Em;
        exit when a%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line(Em.EName);
        end loop;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code by using an implicit cursor ( `T` must be provided to the code block below, of course):

```
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (
        SELECT *
          FROM emp
         WHERE deptno = T
    ) LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(i.EName);
    END LOOP;
END;
```